# Combie dataframes horizontally without common column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a pretty simple problem, but I am new to R. I have over 300 dataframes such as these:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(1:10,5,rep=TRUE)))
DF2 <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(11:20,8,rep=TRUE)))
DF3 <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(21:30,3,rep=TRUE)))
```

I make a list out of them:

```
list <- lapply(paste0('DF',seq(1,3)), get)
```

My goal is to combine these data frames and print them side by side. The reason i cannot use functions list merge, cbind 
is that I dont wish to combine according to any column as reference.

```
        [DF][1]
```

Now, cbind.fill() from the rowr package does the job when I pass the DFs seperately. But how do I pass the list to it?
It does not work when I do cbind.fill(list)

After searching I found merge_recurse(list), but it does not do the job.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `do.call`

```
library(rowr)
res1 <- do.call(cbind.fill, lst)
identical(res1, cbind.fill(DF1, DF2, DF3))
#[1] TRUE
```

It is better not to name objects with function names, i.e. we could name it as 'lst' instead of 'list'.  Also, for multiple objects, we can use `mget` instead of 'get'

```
lst <- mget(paste0('DF', 1:3))
```

---

This can also be done without any package.  We can replicate the rows by the maximum row in the `list` of datasets and then `cbind`

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, function(x) x[rep(1:nrow(x), 
                     length.out= max(sapply(lst, nrow))),]))
```